# Fetching single item vs fetching multiple items with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I'm currently working on application that has the following:

- A 'courses' page that will display all courses with accompanying information
  from the database.
- A 'course' page that will display a single course with accompanying information from the database

My coursesAction file has an action function for fetching a single course from the server and another action function for fetching all courses from the server. Should I use a seperate reducer for handling a list of courses vs a single course since my initialState is an empty array (meant for a list of course objects)? rather than an empty object(meant for a course object)?:

```
let initialState =  [];

export default function courseReducer(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case types.LOAD_COURSES_SUCCESS:
            return  action.courses;    
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Or should I instead retrieve all courses from the server and then when navigating to my 'course' page query the course I'm looking for from the store??

Comment: Same reducer, different switch case

Comment: Would you add the single course to an array? Since that's what my initial state is producing

Comment: I take it back, different reducer is better. Personally, I would make it a single object with all of the properties, but it's up to you. In this case, there's no "wrong way".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well create two reducers for two different actions is not a bad idea but if you just want to separate it due to initial state datatype problem then you do not need to make it separate. Both can be handled in a single way.
Use immutable, which is also a good practice if you are using react + rediux

**Import immutable**

```
import {Record} from 'immutable'
```

**Make initial state object as follow**

```
const Initialstate = new Record({
    course: {},
    courses: []
})
```

**Your reducer be like**

```
export default function courseReducer(state = new Initialstate(), action = {}){
    switch(action.type){
        case types.LOAD_COURSES_SUCCESS:
            return  action.courses;
        case types.LOAD_COURSE_SUCCESS:
            return  action.course;    
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Also, you can change state in reducer like below, if require in future.

```
case types.LOAD_CUSTOM:
            return state.set("customPhase", "success")
```

Comment: That's actually a really good idea on having both! Let's say you already had all courses loaded in your courses[] array within the redux store, would you still perform a api call to the server to retrieve that course or would you instead query the existing courses state to find the course with matching Id?

Also thanks for the tip on immutable! I'll check it out!

Comment: Ummm.. If we think like this then, No, I do not perform API call for the single course to reduce time and server load.

`But but but` Database could be changed after we have all course, then it causes an issue. So it is preferable to do API call.

Comment: Yea my course info is pretty static, but yes in other scenarios where my state is more likely to change I would definitively make the api call. Thanks!